# How do I get access to resources in my test classes when using robolectric

Tags: android, robolectric

I have made a text file of values that I want to use for testing in res/raw
I want to use them in testing
I am using robolectric
What is the best way of accessing these values?
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

wooops, I really should do more research before I post questions
robolectric has got resource support https://github.com/robolectric/robolectric

Answer (score 7):

You can access your app's resources via your Application instance. Use ApplicationProvider to fetch it from within a unit test:

```
// replace 'Application' with your actual class if you use a custom one
ApplicationProvider.getApplicationContext<Application>().resources
```

Ensure includeAndroidResources is set to true in your `build.gradle` or your unit tests won't see your resources:

```
android {
    testOptions.unitTests.includeAndroidResources true
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I have done this as :

```
int resourceId = Robolectric.getShadowApplication().getResources()
                 .getIdentifier("myaudio","raw", Robolectric.getShadowApplication().getPackageName()); 

if (resourceId != 0) {  // Raw folder contains resource.
    assertTrue(true);
} else {                // Raw folder doesn't contain resource.
    assertTrue(false);
}
```

Hope this help...!!
Thanks..!!

Comment: Why not use `RuntimeEnvironment.application` instead of **Robolectric.getShadowApplication**?